# Help filtering childs

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
$(".button-banc").hover(function() {
    $(".button-banc img")
        .animate({ top: "-21px" }, 200).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 200) // first jump
        .animate({ top: "-19px" }, 100).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 100) // second jump
        .animate({ top: "-18px" }, 100).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 100); // the last jump
});
```

The effect I want is: when you pass the mouse over an image this image should jump a bit. The problem is that I got "some" images with the class "button-banc" and I want this behaive:

When you pass the mouse over, "only the actual image" should jump. The problem is that with the code I posted, every image jumps.

How can I achieve this, please help; I want to make a generic way, so that if I add images with the class, they also behaive like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the top of your function to use `this`, like this:

```
$(".button-banc img").hover(function() {
   $(this).animate({ top: "-21px" }, 200).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 200) // first jump
          .animate({ top: "-19px" }, 100).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 100) // second jump
          .animate({ top: "-18px" }, 100).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 100); // the last jump
});
```

This selector attaches the hover the images in the same container with that class and animates only **that** image, because the image you're hovering over is what `this` is in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button-banc").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img")
        .animate({ top: "-21px" }, 200).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 200) // first jump
        .animate({ top: "-19px" }, 100).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 100) // second jump
        .animate({ top: "-18px" }, 100).animate({ top: "-17px" }, 100); // the last jump
});
```